# unrecognized selector sent to instance + crash when pressing UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get the NSException "unrecognized selector sent to instance" and then my app crashes whenever the btnReload UIBarButtonItem is pressed. I included the code for what the method does for the action, however the crash/exception **occurs whether or not the testChangingViewController method has code.**

All of the following code is in my UIViewController class.

```
- (void)loadView //use loadView because not a storyboard based GUI.
{
    [super loadView];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnReload =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(testChangingViewController:)];
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnReload;
    btnReload.enabled=TRUE;

    //self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScr een mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self setTitle:@"Navigation"]; //navigation bar title tied to the view controller it is managing.

    UIImageView *friendsIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"change_user-512"]];
    [friendsIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 130, 70, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:friendsIcon];

    UIImageView *statusIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk-512"]];
    [statusIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(180,130, 70, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:statusIcon];

    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 250, 50, 50)];
    [square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:square];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



-(void)testChangingViewController
{
    UITableViewController *newViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should post the entire error message, but your error is obvious -- you say the selector should be "testChangingViewController:" (with the colon), but you implemented the method testChangingViewController, without a colon.

Comment: -1 for not including the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the UIBarButtonItem the @selector(testChangingViewController:) (colon at end, one parameter) but you define the method testChangingViewController (no colon, no params). The selector it is looking for that takes a parameter is not present, hence your error. These target selectors always tend to have one parameter, the "sender", that is, the UIControl that generated the event.

Comment: AAHHH thank you sir. Where can I learn more about the different types of events in ios? E.x. "These target selectors always tend to have one parameter, the "sender", that is, the UIControl that generated the event." Why would I need this?

Comment: You're welcome! I live for upvotes and checkmarks ;) That parameter is useful because you could have more than one button or control that all have the same selector as their action. Then in that method, you can check which control generated the event and do different things.
Check out UIControlEvents under "Constants" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65